# Is there any stablecoin except for DAI that is stable against the dollar without actually being backed by physical dollars?

Tags: stablecoins, synthetix

Is there any stablecoin except for DAI that is stable against the dollar without actually being backed by physical dollars?

Perhaps backed by CDP or some other method?

Vesa

Comment: Probably depends on your definition of "stable". And I assume you mean stablecoins based on Ethereum. I bet there are tons of such stablecoins but their stability might be questionable.

Comment: I do not think DAI qualifies as stable as the moment.

Answer (score 1):

there is a big development in Switzerland with private digital Swiss Francs in various forms. Most prominent are xCHF (not very stable but scales fine) and dCHF stable but does not scale for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As a DAI competitor we have Synthetix USD or sUSD: [Please find more information about sUSD here](https://blog.kyber.network/synth-usd-susd-is-now-available-on-kyber-network-7f5e11a550ea).

Then we have multiple layered DAI implementations, [like interest accruing aDAI](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/elxjnd/the_aave_protocol_is_live_flash_loans_adai_rate/).